# If the numbers after the decimal is zero, it doesn’t return as a double value?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5

I'm having an index created in `elasticsearch 5.0`, where it contains data from my `MySQL` db.  There's a field which is a `string` in my table, which I need it as a `double` in ES.

So what I did was added the mapping when I created the index for the appropriate field using a `PUT`:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "my_type": {
      "properties": {      
        "chargeamount": {
          "type": "double"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

After I did this, a value which contains numbers after the decimal (ie: 23.23) returns the value properly as a double but where as numbers which has zeros after the decimal (ie: 23.00) returns it as a string itself (ie: 2300).

**EDIT**:
These are the steps which I did:

1. I initially created the index through a `PUT` request
   (`http://hostmachine:9402/indexname`) with the above mapping as the
   body.
2. Then I'm pushing the data (from my MySQL table) to the index using
       `logstash`. I could provide the logstash conf if needed.
3. Once the data is being uploaded to the index, I tried querying as such in order to check whether the result shows a double value. The `POST` request (`http://hostmachine:9402/indexname/_search?` and the body as follows :

   ```
   {  
           "size" : 0,
          "query":{  
             "query_string":{  
                "query":"myquery"
             }
          },
          "aggs":{  
             "total":{  
                "terms":{  
                   "field":"userid"
                },
                "aggs":{  
                   "total":{  
                      "sum":{  
                          "script":{
                           "lang": "painless",
                           "inline" : "doc['chargeamount'].value"
                          }
                      }
                   }
                }
             }
          }
       }
   ```

And the result looks like as in the snapshot below, where it should've been **267472.00**:

[image]

Where am I going wrong? Any help could be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show an example of the document you have indexed, and the commands you're running?

Comment: @Val example of the document in the sense? 
I created the index using this (`http://hostmachine:9402/indexname` ) put request with the above mapping as the `body`. After I created the index as such I'm trying to upload data to the index using `logstash`.

Comment: In simpler terms, can you show all the commands you ran so that one could recreate the same issue as you see?

Comment: Ok now can you show two documents you've sourced from MySQL? One with `chargeamount` having decimals (e.g. 23.23) and another one without (e.g. 23.00).

Comment: @Val you want me to show it from the db itself, or after querying in ES?

Comment: I would like to see a document as it is indexed in ES, basically what you get from `curl -XGET localhost:9200/indexname/typename/id`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127080/discussion-between-kulasangar-and-val).

Comment: @Val I've posted the results after including "_source": ["chargeamount"], within the request body in the above discussion.

Comment: I've answered back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that the mapping type in your index creation query is exactly the same as the `document_type` you have in your logstash config, namely `message_logs`:

```
PUT response_summary6
{
  "mappings": {
    "message_logs": {          <--- change this
      "properties": {
        "userid": {
          "type": "text",
          "fielddata": true
        },
        "responsecode": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "chargeamount": {
          "type": "double"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```